# What is the probability of pregnancy per instance of condom-protected intercourse?

Tags: probability, bayesian

I’m trying to find out what the average probability of pregnancy despite condom usage is. Specifically, what is the probability that:

1. Someone with female sex gets pregnant,
2. Through a single event of “penis-in-vagina” type intercourse (not, e.g., per year),
3. With someone with male sex,
4. Despite correct condom usage per the operationalization below,
5. While assuming that both are basically fertile,
6. But while averaging out changing levels of fertility at different times?

A lot of sources give rather unhelpful information. For example, [Planned Parenthood](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/birth-control/condom/how-effective-are-condoms) says:

> If you use condoms perfectly every single time you have sex, they’re 98% effective at preventing pregnancy. But people aren’t perfect, so in real life condoms are about 85% effective — that means about 15 out of 100 people who use condoms as their only birth control method will get pregnant each year.

First I misread this as a probability per intercourse and was quite shocked by the apparent 2% probability, but now that I noticed the “per year” bit, it’s still puzzling to me because I don’t know whether these people had sex, say, 1 or 365 times per year.

I started out with a prior of a $\frac{1}{500}$ probability of pregnancy, so if my prior is correct and accidents are uncorrelated, then these people had sex 10 times per year on average, and I can’t tell whether that’s unrealistically high or low, so I can’t adjust my prior on that basis.

The study “[Efficacy of a combined contraceptive regimen consisting of condoms and emergency contraception pills](https://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2458-14-354#)” says:

> The frequency of intercourse between the intervention group and the condom only group was 60.7 ± 17.9 and 58.5 ± 18.7, respectively, per year.

So about 60 times in that particular study.

It gives a “cumulative gross pregnancy rate” as follows:

> The gross cumulative life table rates were calculated for pregnancy and other reasons for discontinuation. [Table 4](https://bmcpublichealth.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2458-14-354/tables/4) shows the gross pregnancy rates of the two groups. The cumulative gross pregnancy rates in the intervention group and the control group were 2.17 ± 0.52 and 1.25 ± 0.41, respectively, per 100 women.

So about 2% per year – unless that’s counting these “other reasons for discontinuation,” which I’m probably not interested in.

So that suggests a probability of $\frac{2\%}{60} = \frac{1}{3000} \approx 0.03\%$, so they’re about 99.97% safe, which is much safer than my prior, which makes me suspicious that I might be misreading the study.

They operationalize correct usage as:

> a. a condom should be used for every instance of sexual intercourse; b. check if condom is broken before using it; c. exhaust the air from the top bubble; d. hold the base of the condom while drawing the penis out of the vagina; e. if breakage, leakage, or slippage occurs, an emergency method should be used.

That sounds about right to me.

I haven’t looked at other studies, but the discussion section of this study suggests that their results were typical for RCTs:

> But in the randomized and controlled studies in which latex condoms were usually used as the control methods compared with other methods, the pregnancy rate is at a low level, just like in our study.

There’s now a huge range between the very optimistic $\frac{1}{3000}$ probability of the study, my $\frac{1}{500}$ prior, and the once-per-year sex interpretation of the Planned Parenthood data for a $\frac{1}{50}$ probability. (The $\frac{1}{7}$ probability based on “But people aren’t perfect, so in real life condoms are about 85% effective” can probably be ignored here because it’s not based on RCTs and includes a lot of instances of wrong usage?)

The last one, $\frac{1}{50}$ or even $\frac{1}{7}$, seems highly unlikely (it’s probably based on ~ 60 times rather than 1 time per year, too), but the range still seems worryingly wide to me. Further, it seems that none of these sources are even interested in calculating this probability at all even though it seems like *the* central most important probability to me, so I’m afraid I’m missing something crucial here.

Am I misreading the study in some fashion? Is the study unrepresentative of what I’m interested in? Do some of my shakey assumptions (e.g., that the probabilities per intercourse are uncorrelated or any tacit assumptions) have a relevant effect? Do you have a best guess what the true probability is in this setting? Or am I only interested in this probability because I’m thinking too Bayesian-like and others find it irrelevant?